# using argparse, getting KeyError

Tags: python, argparse

```
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2 as cv

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("-i", "--input image", required=True, help='Input the Image')
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output image", required=True, help='Output the Image')

args = vars(ap.parse_args())

img = cv.imread(args["input"])

gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gaussian = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

threshold = cv.threshold(gaussian, 60, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

contr = cv.findContours(threshold.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contr = imutils.grab_contours(contr)

for c in contr:
    cv.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

txt = 'Yes I Found {} the Shapes in Image'.format(len(contr))
textPut = cv.putText(img, txt, (10, 20), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv.imshow(args["output"], img)
```

Comment: how did you call this?  normally you would supply the --input="filename.whatever"  to your script on starting it - in an IDE this will not be done automagically for you ...

Comment: add `print(args)` aftter `args = vars(ap.parse_args())`  to see whats stored at "input" key - guess its not there at all.#

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Let's reduce your code to a MWVE:

```
#test.py
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument("-i", "--input image", required=True, help='Input the Image')
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output image", required=True, help='Output the Image')

args = vars(ap.parse_args())
print(args)
```

running this with

```
python test.py -i input.jpg -o output.jpg
```

gives

```
{'input image': 'input.jpg', 'output image': 'output.jpg'}
```

The issue is that you misused the second argument, it is not a `flag` + description, but only the flag, which is then used as the key. You should do it like this:

```
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True, help='Input the Image')
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True, help='Output the Image')
```

Replacing that in above code and running with `python test.py -i input.jpg -o output.jpg` gives now:

```
{'input': 'input.jpg', 'output': 'output.jpg'}
```

You can also set the name of the field used in `args` explicitly, e.g.:

```
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True, help='Input the Image', dest="in")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True, help='Output the Image', dest="out")
```

which will give

```
{'in': 'input.jpg', 'out': 'output.jpg'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd only get `keyError` if the argument doesn't exist.

When I received this error, I was confident that I had the `key/argument` so I kept on running my code again and again without reviewing the code and kept on getting keyError repeatedly. I checked my code and it turns out that I had somehow removed that particular `argument` mistakenly.